# creating 3 articles on wordpress homepage

Tags: wordpress

I am quite new and am creating a wordpress childtheme based on thematic.

On my front page I want to have 3 boxes with short articles in them that link into other pages/posts.

At the moment I was thinking of creating the homepage as a static page and somehow bringing in 3 posts via their ids.  I know I'd have to do something with the loop...

Is this possible?

Perhaps I'd be better just using widgets which I know I can do?

I'd really appreciate any pointers because I am unsure of the best way forward

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a shortcode is better option for you.

1. With short code you can use it anywhere, direct into the php or in the editor
2. you can control the boxes range by setting the extra parameters.

like :

```
add_shortcode("my_custom_posts", "shortcode_callback");
function shortcode_callback($atts, $content=null){
   // your query to fetch the short articles
}
```

Now your next question maybe, How to create shortcodes, then please take a look on the [codex documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) or there are more articles over the internet.

If you still getting puzzle then take a look on this article that describe the steps to get the recent articles from the post...
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/01/wordpress-shortcodes-complete-guide/

Comment: I actually never though of using a shortcode as such. Between a widget and shortcode, coded correctly, you can actually make is as dynamic as you want :-) +1

Comment: In the end I went with shortcode added into a widget. Really great answer jogesh_pi - thanks!